# Arrayformula function keep getting error different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

I'm trying to sum rows with specific criteria with the following formula:

`=ArrayFormula(sum(countifs(disposition,"Consultation" ,Primary,{"","OB_Gyn","Surgical"},Consultations,{"*IM*","*Cardio*","*Nephro*","*Neuro*","*GI*",""})))`

where `disposition`, `Primary`, `Consultations` are NamedRanges of columns with same rows 9-58.
But I get the error message.

> **#value!**
> Array arguments to COUNTIFS are of different size.

Comment: Please share your test sheet.

Comment: <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUk3hUwL2CcePR4aKXU746DQTVdTVE5_lICpYSKBLpg/edit?usp=drivesdk>

Comment: Its D13 in 'statistics' sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT
(following OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/150231/arrayformula-function-keep-getting-error-different-sizes#comment136940_150234)

> I need exactly all criteria . If disposition is "consultation " AND primary is either "Ob"or"surgical" And consultation contains eithe" IM"or "cardio"....

You can easily alter the formula with something like the following

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(
                N(REGEXMATCH({disposition, Primary, Consultations},"xx|yy|Neuro|GI")),
                N(REGEXMATCH({disposition},"zz|ABD")),
                N(REGEXMATCH({Primary},"Cardio|Nephro")),
                COUNTBLANK(disposition),
                COUNTBLANK(Primary)
                                        ))
```

The basic difference is `COUNTBLANK` that we bring in our formula because we can not count blanks using the regex.

---

**Original answer**

Instead of your countifs formula you could try the following

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(N(REGEXMATCH({disposition, Primary, Consultations}, 
                                  "IM|Cardio|Nephro|Neuro|GI"))))
```

**What the formula does**

1. Using the `REGEXMATCH` in combination with the `ArrayFormula` function we come up with `TRUE` or `FALSE` results.
2. Because though,  `TRUE` and `FALSE` correspond to `1` and `0` values, we use the `N` function to turn them to `1`s and `0`s respectively.
3. Finally we `SUM` to get the desired result.

Comment: Well, I need exactly all criteria . If disposition is "consultation " AND primary is either "Ob"or"surgical" And consultation contains eithe" IM"or "cardio"....

Comment: Please check the edited answer.

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and **even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well**.